# ¿Por que no me arroja el resultado de la consulta en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, poo, pdo

junto con saludar les escribo por que veo y veo el código y aun no encuentro el error. Sin embargo esto es lo que arroja:

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected in C:\xampp\htdocs\Curso PHP\devuelve_paises.php:19 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Curso PHP\devuelve_paises.php(19): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Curso PHP\indexPOO_PDO.php(9): DevuelveProductos->getProductos('USA') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Curso PHP\devuelve_paises.php on line 19

En el capitulo 58 del curso de Píldoras informáticas enseñan como conectarse a una base de datos a través de PDO con POO.

este es el link del video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rw96Tb0nfZc&list=PLU8oAlHdN5BkinrODGXToK9oPAlnJxmW_&index=58

estos son los archivos:

//config.php

```
<?php

    define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
    define("DB_USUARIO", "root");
    define("DB_CONTRA", "");
    define("DB_NOMBRE", "pruebas");
    define("DB_CHARSET", "utf8");

?>
```

//conexion.php

```
<?php

    require ("config.php");

    class Conexion{
        
        protected $conexion_db;
        
        //constructor
        public function __construct(){

            try{
                
                $this->conexion_db = new PDO("mysql:host = localhost; dbname = pruebas" , "root", "");

                $this->conexion_db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                
                $this->conexion_db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
                
                return $this->conexion_db;
                
            }catch(Exception $e){
                
                echo "La línea de error es " . $e->getLine();
                
            }
            
            
            /*******************************************************************************/
            
            /*$this->conexion_db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USUARIO, DB_CONTRA, DB_NOMBRE);
            
            if($this->conexion_db->connect_errno){
                
                echo "Fallo al conectar a MySQL: " . $this->conexion_db->connect_error;
                
                return;
                
            }
            
            $this->conexion_db->set_charset(DB_CHARSET);*/
            
        }
            
    }

?>
```

//devuelve_paises.php

```
<?php

    require ("conexion.php");

    class DevuelveProductos extends Conexion{
        
        public function __construct(){
            
            parent::__construct();
            
        }
        
        public function getProductos($dato){
            
            $query = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE PAIS_DE_ORIGEN_ARTICULO = '" . $dato . "'";
            
            $sentencia = $this->conexion_db->prepare($query);
            
            $sentencia->execute(array());
            
            $resultado = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            
            $sentencia->closeCursor();
            
            return $resultado;
            
            $this->conexion_db = null;
            
            /*$resultado = $this->conexion_db->query("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE PAIS_DE_ORIGEN_ARTICULO = '" . $dato . "'");
            
            $productos = $resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            
            return $productos;*/
            
        }
        
    }
        

?>
```

//index_POO_PDO.php

```
<?php

    require ("devuelve_paises.php");

    $pais = $_GET["buscar"];
    //se instancia o se crea un objeto
    $productos = new DevuelveProductos();
    //se crea variable que almacena array
    $array_productos = $productos->getProductos($pais);
    
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>
    
    <?php
    
        foreach($array_productos as $elemento){
            
            echo "<table>";
            echo    "<tr>";
            echo        "<td>" . $elemento["CODIGO_ARTICULO"] . "</td>";
            echo        "<td>" . $elemento["NOMBRE_ARTICULO"] . "</td>";
            echo        "<td>" . $elemento["SECCION_ARTICULO"] . "</td>";
            echo        "<td>" . $elemento["PRECIO_ARTICULO"] . "</td>";
            echo        "<td>" . $elemento["FECHA_ARTICULO"] . "</td>";
            echo        "<td>" . $elemento["IMPORTADO_ARTICULO"] . "</td>";
            echo        "<td>" . $elemento["PAIS_DE_ORIGEN_ARTICULO"] . "</td>";
            echo    "</tr>";
            echo "<table>";
            
            echo "<br>";

        }
    
    ?>
    
</body>
</html>
```

//formulario_busqueda_paises_POO.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="indexPOO_PDO.php" method="get">
        <label>Introduce país: <input type="text" name="buscar"></label>
        <input type="submit" name="enviando" value="Dale!">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lo que te dice es que no encuentra la db que referenciaste en config.php

Comment: Tal ves la pregunta es un poco tonta pero ya creaste la base de datos ? o ya ejecutaste tu tu servidor mysql para poder permitir extraer datos de la DB? Revisa también las direcciones de tus importaciones(require o include) tal vez no estas enlazando bien los archivos.

Comment: Nunca he visto que se use espacios en el DSN. Prueba así : `$this->conexion_db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pruebas" , "root", "")` Supongo que la BD `pruebas` existe realmente.

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda de todas formas. Aún no lo puedo solucionar, ya revise el archibo config.php, ya cree la base de datos y probe la query y todo bien, por ultimo junte las lineas y nada. Reitero las gracias. Alguien ya se a conectado a la base de datos con POO y PDO?

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a un suscriptor del canal píldoras informáticas se pudo responder la pregunta.

Solo había que agregar el nombre de la base de la base de datos a la query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM PRUEBAS.PRODUCTOS WHERE PAIS_DE_ORIGEN_ARTICULO = '" . $dato . "'";
```

Gracias por su tiempo de todas formas.